# Remove all views from AndroidYoutubePlayer

Tags: android, youtube-api

I use [PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player) library version 12.0.0 for my project. I want to remove every single view from the player (controls, caption, logo, title, next recomended videos), but I don't understand how.

There is said in library's [README.md](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#remove-annoying-views) how u can do it, but I didn't get it.

Edited:

That is how I added this libary to my project.

```
dependencies {
implementation("com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:12.0.0")
}
```

There is no such methods like

```kotlin
val youtubePlayer = youtubePlayerView.getYoutubePlayer()
```

```kotlin
youtubePlayerView.hideControls()
```

```kotlin
youtubePlayer.showVideoTitle(false)
```

```kotlin
youTubePlayer.cueVideo("")
```

```kotlin
youtubePlayer.setShowYouTubeButton(false)
```

That is how I added YoutubePlayer to my project (with Jetpack Compose)

```kotlin
@Composable
fun YoutubeScreen(videoId: String) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = {
        YouTubePlayerView(it).apply {

            enableAutomaticInitialization = false

            val youtubePlayerListener = object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                    super.onReady(youTubePlayer)
                    youTubePlayer.apply {
                        loadVideo(videoId, 0f)
                        play()
                    }
                }
            }

            /*
              controls(0) removes controls, but tile, youtube logo,
              etc. are still visible.
            */

            val playerOptions = IFramePlayerOptions.Builder()
                .controls(0)
                .build()

            initialize(
                youTubePlayerListener = youtubePlayerListener,
                handleNetworkEvents = true,
                playerOptions = playerOptions
            )
        }
    })
}
```